# Reading /proc file with python

Tags: python, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to implement simple firewall as linux kernel module, which communicates with user space app (written in python) using procfs. Everything works fine but reading from /proc/file.

This is code I'm performing on my client:

```
if os.path.isfile(PROCFS_PATH) and os.access(PROCFS_PATH,os.R_OK):
    myfile = open(PROCFS_PATH,'r')
    for line in myfile:
        print line.rstrip("\n")

    myfile.close()
```

It's just a simple print.

This is proc readfile from kernel module:

```
static ssize_t procRead(struct file *fp, char *buffer, size_t len, loff_t *offset){

static int finished = 0;

if(finished)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "proc read finished. Read: %s\n", buffer);
    finished = 0;
    return 0;
}

finished = 1;

if(copy_to_user(buffer, buf, procBuffSize))
    return -EFAULT;

printk(KERN_INFO "read %lu bytes\n", procBuffSize);

return procBuffSize;
```

}

Guess, it should be fine, but the problem is that I'm getting MemoryError in my client when trying to read. At the momment /proc/file contains simple firewall rule containing 20 chars so file size won't be a problem. What is?

Comment: Can you cat the file from a console? Does it show the proper format? Using the same user/permissions like the Python program?

Comment: What is the size of file on procfs? Anyway, it is safer to use [`seq_file`](http://linux.die.net/lkmpg/x861.html) in procfs code.

Comment: Using static 'finished' flag is not a good idea: this exhibits  incorrect behaviour in case, e.g., when the file is read byte by byte. 'return simple_read_from_buffer(buffer, len, offset, buf, procBuffSize);' is the simplest implementation for your 'procRead' function, try to rewrite code using it.

Comment: @Olaf yes I can cat the file, showing file content in correct format

Comment: @myaut ls -l returns that file size is actually 0... its strange because it contains some data if i cat the file